# Problema con los campos auto-calculados en una tabla

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py

Tengo esta tabla :

```
db.define_table('cotizaciones',
                Field('numero_ticket', 'reference tickets'),
                Field('numero_cotizacion', 'string'),
                Field('fecha_registro_cotizacion', 'date', default=now),
                Field('reporte_adjunto', 'upload'),
                Field('cliente', 'reference clientes', default='',requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.clientes, '%(cliente)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                #Field('marca_gg', 'reference marcas_definiciones', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.marcas_definiciones, '%(marca)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('contacto_cotizacion', 'reference contactos', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.contactos, '%(contacto_cliente)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('fecha_cotizacion', 'date',default=now),
                Field('servicio_producto_cotizacion', 'reference servicios_productos', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.servicios_productos, '%(servicio_producto)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('tipo_trabajo', 'reference tipos_trabajos', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.tipos_trabajos, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('tipo_horario', 'reference tipos_horarios', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.tipos_horarios, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('tipo_cotizacion', 'reference tipos_cotizaciones', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.tipos_cotizaciones, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('plazo_ejecucion_promedio', 'string', default="Null"),
                Field('moneda', 'reference monedas', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.monedas, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('alcances_servicio', 'reference alcances_servicios', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.alcances_servicios, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('aplica_adicionales', 'boolean'),
                Field('aplica_penalidades', 'boolean'),
                Field('plazo_pago', 'reference plazos_pagos', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.plazos_pagos, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('calidad_acabado', 'reference calidades_acabados', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.calidades_acabados, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('calidad_material', 'reference calidades_materiales' ,requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.calidades_materiales, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('calidad_limpieza', 'reference calidades_limpieza' ,requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.calidades_limpieza, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('disposicion_desmonte', 'reference disposiciones_desmonte' ,requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.disposiciones_desmonte, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('tiempo_garantia', 'reference tiempos_garantia', requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, db.tiempos_garantia, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----'))),
                Field('porcentaje_gastos_generales', type='decimal(10,2)'),
                Field('porcentaje_utilidad', type='decimal(10,2)'),
                Field('porcentaje_descuento', type='decimal(10,2)'),
                Field('porcentaje_igv', type='decimal(10,2)'),
                Field('costo_directo',type='decimal(10,2)'),
                Field('gastos_generales',
                      compute=lambda r: round((r['costo_directo'] * r['porcentaje_gastos_generales'] )/ 100)),
                Field('utilidad', compute=lambda r: round((r['costo_directo'] * r['porcentaje_utilidad']) / 100)),
                Field('sub_total',
                      compute=lambda r: round(r['costo_directo'] + r['gastos_generales'] + r['utilidad'])),
                Field('descuento', compute=lambda r: round((r['sub_total'] * r['porcentaje_descuento'] )/ 100)),
                Field('sub_total_venta', compute=lambda r: round(r['sub_total'] - r['descuento'])),
                Field('impuesto_igv', compute=lambda r: round((r['sub_total_venta'] * r['porcentaje_igv'])/100)),
                Field('total_venta', compute=lambda r: round(r['sub_total'] + r['impuesto_igv'])),
                Field('cotizacion_adjunto', 'upload'),
                Field('observaciones', 'text'),
                Field('nota', 'text'),
                format='%(numero_cotizacion)s')
```

Que debe hacer cálculo automático, pero al procesar me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es la función `round`, en Python 2 te retorna un `float` incluso si le pasas como parámetro un `Decimal`, como estás usando campo de tipo `decimal(m, n)` internamente web2py está usando un `Decimal` para representar los montos de tus campos.

**Python 2.7.6:**

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> round(Decimal('99.99'), 2)
99.99
>>> type(round(Decimal('99.99'), 2))
float
```

**Python 3.4.3:**

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> round(Decimal('99.99'), 2)
Decimal('99.99')
>>> type(round(Decimal('99.99'), 2))
decimal.Decimal
```

Entonces como en tu campo calculado estás usando esto:

```
lambda r: round(r['costo_directo'] + r['gastos_generales'] + r['utilidad'])
```

Pero a la vez, el campo `gastos_generales` es computado y retorna un valor redondeado (en `float`), es por eso que te sale el error al tratar de sumar `costo_directo` con `gastos_generales` (`Decimal` + `float`):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

Bien, lo anterior era solo para identificar el problema, el tema es que para redondear montos con objetos decimales, el proceso es distinto. Te recomiento usar [`quantize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> Decimal('5.504').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('5.50')
>>> Decimal('5.505').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('5.51')
```

Lo ideal sería que tengas algún tipo de función definida a la cual puedas llamar para redondear los montos:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

def redondear(monto, exponente=Decimal('.01')):
    return monto.quantize(exponente, rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Con la función anterior podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
>>> redondear(Decimal('0.5444444')) # 2 decimales por defecto
Decimal('0.54')
>>> redondear(Decimal('0.5444444'), exponente=Decimal('.001')) # 3 decimales
Decimal('0.544')
>>> redondear(Decimal('0.5444444'), exponente=Decimal('.0001')) # 4 decimales
Decimal('0.5444')
```

Regresando a web2py, puedes cambiar las funciones `lambda` de tus campos computados por algo así:

```
lambda r: redondear(r['costo_directo'] + r['gastos_generales'] + r['utilidad'])
```